# SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read server certificate A

Tags: https, openssl

Some of Servers print out "SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read server certificate A" when I connect some https sites by openssl.

I want to build CI(Continue Integration) project by Jenkins, But I can't download and update plugins normally.

I found out the real link(https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn) for downloading plugins used by Jenkins, and tried to connect it by openssl(My Usage:openssl s_client -connect mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn:443 -state).

After that, the error message was printed out.

> CONNECTED(00000003)
>
> SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
>
> SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
>
> SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
>
> SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read server certificate A
>
> SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read server certificate A
>
> write:errno=104
>
> ---
>
> no peer certificate available
>
> ---
>
> No client certificate CA names sent
>
> ---
>
> SSL handshake has read 1448 bytes and written 0 bytes
>
> ---
>
> New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
>
> Secure Renegotiation IS supported
>
> Compression: NONE
>
> Expansion: NONE
>
> No ALPN negotiated
>
> SSL-Session:
>
> ```
> Protocol  : TLSv1.2
>
> Cipher    : 0000
>
> Session-ID: 
>
> Session-ID-ctx: 
>
> Master-Key: 
>
> Key-Arg   : None
>
> Krb5 Principal: None
>
> PSK identity: None
>
> PSK identity hint: None
>
> Start Time: 1545705198
>
> Timeout   : 300 (sec)
>
> Verify return code: 0 (ok)
> ```
>
> ---

I don't know which parts the error occur in. I expect someones who can tell me how can I fix it. Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the output of `openssl version`?

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017